# Why will my Datagridview not display information from the DataTable to which I bound it?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have created a form with a datagridview on it. I bound that DGV to a datatable which is constructed from a table in a SqlServer CE database. I was able to add, edit and delete records and save changes to the database.

Then, I set AutoGenerateColumns to False so I could set up the DGV with nice formatting. To begin, I added only one column:

```
'/// Set Up DataGridView
    With dgvMaterials
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        '.Columns.Add("MaterialName", "Material")

    End With
    Dim col As DataGridViewColumn
    '
    col = New DataGridViewColumn
    With col
        .Name = "Material"
        .DataPropertyName = "MaterialName"
        .Width = 200

        '.HeaderText = "Material"
    End With
    dgvMaterials.Columns.Add(col)
    dgvMaterials.DataSource = stuff.Materials
```

(Stuff is an instance of a class where I do my SQL stuff, Materials is the name of the DataTable)

Now I must have checked DataPropertyName a hundred times and I verified that there are records in the DataTable, but they will not show in the DGV. Why?

As always thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Could you instead just select one item from `stuff.Materials`, something along the lines of `dgvMaterials.DataSource = stuff.Materials.Select(Function(m) m.MaterialName).ToList()`?

Comment: Does it work with `AutoGenerateColumns = True` and not building the columns yourself? You may need to have all the columns setup before binding to it with only one column.

Comment: Yes, it does work that way - but not with 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, the answer is simple: I put my column in as type DataGridViewColumn and for whatever reason it had to be DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to work. I switched it out, now the datagridview works like a champ.